# Canada travel to US using Global Entry

Tags: canada, global-entry

We are taking a cruise from Boston to Montreal with our kids.  We have Gloabal entry cards for all.  We are flying out of Montreal to the US and just realized that my daughter age 16 passsport expired 2 months ago.

Cruise line says ok for Global entry documentation.  We can not get an answer for air travel.

We leave in 2 weeks.

Comment: Nevermind coming back to the US, you can't enter Canada without a passport.

Comment: Where are you starting your trip, Canada or Boston?

Comment: To clarify, you are Canadian citizens who are flying from Montreal to Boston, then taking a cruise back to Montreal?

Answer (score 18):

Global Entry cards cannot be used to enter the US by air under any circumstances.

See https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/card: "We accept Global Entry cards for lawful U.S. entry at land and sea ports of entry."  There is pointedly no mention of "air".

You should look into expedited passport renewal for your daughter.

Answer (score 2):

Your bigger problem will be getting into Canada in the first place. You can't enter Canada (or virtually any other country other than your own) with an expired passport.

[According to the U.S. Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Canada.html), U.S. citizens must have a passport that is valid at the time of entry to enter Canada.

That said, Nate's answer is correct. You need your passport to use the Global Entry kiosks at an airport.

According to [CBP's Global Entry FAQ](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/frequently-asked-questions) (emphasis mine):

> How are Global Entry cards used?
>   CBP accepts Global Entry cards for lawful U.S. entry at land and sea ports of entry. Global Entry cards have radio frequency identification, which enables their use at SENTRI and NEXUS expedited travel lanes entering the U.S. Global Entry cards are not valid for entry into Canada via the NEXUS lanes and kiosks. **Global Entry cards are not accepted at Global Entry kiosks, which require passports or U.S. lawful permanent resident cards.** Global Entry card holders must follow all program rules for SENTRI and NEXUS when using this card at land and sea ports of entry.

Your best course of action is to try to get your daughter's passport renewed ASAP. [According to the Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html), being within 2 weeks of travel, you should schedule an appointment with a [passport agency](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/requirements/where-to-apply/passport-agencies.html) immediately.

Comment: From the question ("We are **flying out of Montreal** to the US " and then "taking a **cruise from Boston to Montreal**"), I think OP is Canadian.  Thus, your answer doesn't seem to answer her question.

Comment: @RonJohn The question does not say "then." It lists cruising from Boston to Montreal first, so I read the question as taking a cruise from Boston to Montreal and then flying back to the U.S. At any rate, my answer answers the question either way. You can neither cruise from Boston to Canada without a passport nor fly from Montreal to the U.S. without a passport, regardless of which you do first. Also, I do not believe Canadian citizens are eligible for Global Entry (unless they're also U.S. citizens or perm residents,) so I'm pretty sure they're not Canadian. Canadians use NEXUS instead.